# Getting the a dictionary item within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

Lets say I have a key:value pair that I want to print, but it is itself inside a dictionary (it's actually JSON data):

```
cslfJson = {'displayFieldName': 'CSLF_ID', 'fieldValues': {'OBJECTID': '13000', 'CSLF_ID': '08123', 'Area_SF': '5431'}}
```

How would I do that? I have tried the following

```
print(cslfJson['OBJECTID'])
>>>KeyError: 'OBJECTID'

print(cslfJson['fieldAliases'['OBJECTID']])
>>>TypeError: string indices must be integers

print(cslfJson['fieldAliases'{'OBJECTID'}])
>>>SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

etc... What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat it as dict inside a dict

```
>>> cslfJson = {'displayFieldName': 'CSLF_ID', 'fieldValues': {'OBJECTID': '13000', 'CSLF_ID': '08123', 'Area_SF': '5431'}}
>>> print(cslfJson['fieldValues']['OBJECTID'])
13000
>>> print(cslfJson['fieldValues']['CSLF_ID'])
08123
```

cheers.

Comment: OK, follow up question. What if it where this: `cslfJson = {'displayFieldName': 'CSLF_ID', 'features': [{'fieldValues': {'OBJECTID': '13000', 'CSLF_ID': '08123', 'Area_SF': '5431'}}]}`?

Comment: does this work? `cslfJson['features'][0]['fieldValues']['OBJECTID']`